# Atlassian Connector for Webstorm

Tags: web, continuous-integration, webstorm, bamboo

I am new with the IDE **WebStorm** and I'm trying to collect the information concerning my Web project. Thus as a result, I look for to know how integrated my ***Webstorm project*** with ***Bamboo*** into **continuous integration**.

Did any more can help me plzz ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the Attlassian Connector plugin (https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/IDEPLUGIN/Supported+Platforms+-+Atlassian+Connector+for+IntelliJ+IDEs). It can be easily installed from the Plugins repository: in Settings/Plugins press Browse Repositories... button, type 'Atlassian connector' in the search box to quickly locate the plugin, double-click to download and install